# Alternatives to MySQL

Tags: database, caching, memcached, scalability

I would like to store data persistently for my application, but I don't really need a full blown relational database. I really could get by with a basic "cache"-like *persistent* storage where the structure is just a (key, value) pair.

In lieu of a database what are my best, scalable options?

Comment: The verdict is in: SQLite! :)

Comment: No one can give a responsible answer to this question without knowing a lot more about what kind of data you are storing in what environment, and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 12):

There's always [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), a database that's stored in a file. SQLite already has built-in concurrency, so you don't have to worry about things like file locking, and it's really fast for reads.

If, however, you are doing lots of database changes, it's best to do them all at once inside a [transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). This will only write the changes to the file once, as opposed to every time an change query is issued. This dramatically increases the speed of doing multiple changes.

When a change query is issued, whether it's inside a tranasction or not, the whole database is locked until that query finishes. This means that extremely large transactions could adversely affect the performance of other processes because they must wait for the transaction to finish before they can access the database. In practice, I haven't found this to be that noticeable, but it's always good practice to try to minimize the number of database modifying queries you issue.

Comment: SQLite is fantastic and easy to integrate into an application. Best of all, there is no client-side installation needed to use it, it's all embedded into the application.

Comment: However, it does have concurrency issues

Answer (score 6):

if you want a 'persistent cache', and already use [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/), check [memcachedb](http://www.memcachedb.org). it's a persistent hashtable using the memcached protocol, no need for a new client (but a new daemon)

Answer (score 3):

I ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260885/storing-large-numbers-of-varying-size-objects-on-disk) recently.  Here are some choices:

- The [Berkley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) is groovy.  (also see the [Berkley DB Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB))
- If you are on Windows, then you can use the built in [Extensible Storage Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684493(VS.85).aspx). This used to be called "Jet Blue".
- [Microsoft SQL Compact Edition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920700) is also free (But not built into the OS.

Comment: ESE is great for big volumes of data, not necessarily as a cache. It works great for AD, Exchange, Wins, FRS, and other technologies.

Answer (score 2):

If you need scalability, then a RDBMS is your best bet. At the most basic level, you can serialize data structures into files - however, then you'd need to account for file locking issues which would limit concurrency.

SQLite is an SQL file-based database engine, which can run without a persistent database daemon (in PHP for example, it runs as an extension), however it too has concurrency issues (read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320803/is-sqlite-suitable-for-use-in-a-production-website) which could help you decide if SQLite is right for you).

Unless you have a really good reason not to use a real DRBMS, I'd suggest you stick with MySQL or other "full-blown" engines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something really scalable, I wouldn't opt for a flat or XML file. As your data grows, it could kill your performance.

If you will have a lot of data *at some stage*, I would still opt for a database - I would take a look at something like [SQLIte](http://www.sqlite.org/) with a very simple schema to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure you *should* but have you considered just storing info in an XML doc if it really is that light? And if it's not have you considered [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If your writing a java program that wants an imbedded database look at [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org) since it is written in java and works much better then sqlite if being called from java programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing Java, then there are Java database implementations (Jared mentions hsqldb, there are others) that you can directly include.

SQLite is fine for static inclusion, however you can also include MySQL within your application if you're using a compatible language such as C.

I think you would appreciate having SQL available as well. XML files just don't cut it any longer, maybe a couple of years ago when writing PDA software, but even the iPhone and Android includes SQLite now.

Answer (score 1):

hsqldb in in-memory mode will give you much better performance than flat file based databases. It's pretty easy to use too. And if the table gets too big, there is an option to cache it on disk too. Check out this performance comparison:

[image: http://hsqldb.org/images/imola_retrieve.jpg]
<sub>(source: [hsqldb.org](http://hsqldb.org/images/imola_retrieve.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For Key=Value pairs, you can use INI file format with simple load and save procedures to load it and save it to in-memory hash table.

That can later scale up to anythig, just by changing load and save procedures to work with db.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CounchDB](http://incubator.apache.org/couchdb/), it is a very flexible document-oriented database that doesn't force you to define a schema up-front. It was written in Erlang and thanks to this it is considered very scalable solution. It can be easily queried through a REST interface.